# updating max_allowed_packet

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I have my application hosted on a shared server, I can't access my.cnf/my.ini file from my account, max_allowed_packet is set to 1M only, Now I need to change it to 32M, is their any idea either by PHP or .htaccess to change its value?

Thanks and Regards
Prajjwal

Comment: possible duplicate of [php.ini configuration changes in shared hosting account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263590/php-ini-configuration-changes-in-shared-hosting-account). In brief: try ini_set(), but shared hosting usually won't let you modify PHP's settings. That's the tradeoff: cheap but limited. As for MySQL settings, no, you can't change those at all on a shared hosting (which is a Good Thing, otherwise everyone would mess with them, making the *shared* hosting all but unusable).

Comment: @Piskvor: I encourage you to even find this variable among PHP settings. It's MySQL's thing, not PHP's

Comment: @Mchl: You are correct. I realized that it's a MySQL setting later, came back and edited that into my previous comment. Alas, can't undo the duplicate vote :(

Answer (score 8):

[`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) allowed for dynamic values, that's mean you just need to login to mysql console

```
show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
set global max_allowed_packet=33554432;
```

logout, and login again

```
show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
```

If you do not have the console login, try PHP should work the same way.

Comment: On a shared hosting? It's theoretically possible that the user can set such globals, but unlikely.

Comment: Indeed, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-option.html ... worse, set as session?